# Why should I avoid doing serious work in -finalize?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, garbage-collection

I've noticed that in Objective-C, doing anything in `-finalize` beyond freeing non-GC'ed memory is frowned upon. The concrete reasons for this I've come across are that:

a) you risk resurrecting the finalized object by sending something a reference to self.
b) you don't know whether the object you're messaging is also being finalized.

Are there any other reasons? And what in particular should be avoided? I'm wondering in particular about allocating new objects, locking the gc thread, using gcd to dispatch a block, and sending a singleton object a performSelectorOnMainThread: message.

To provide a bit of context, I'm writing a class which wraps a type from a C API that makes modifications to a global state when allocated or deallocated. I'm tempted to do something like this:

```
@interface MyWrapper : NSObject
{
    C_API_Type* data;
}
@end

static const* NSString GlobalLock = @"GlobalLock";

@implementation MyWrapper

- (id)init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        @synchronized( GlobalLock )
        {
            data = C_API_Allocate();
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) finalize
{
    @synchronized( GlobalLock )
    {
        C_API_Deallocate(data);
    }

    [super finalize];
}

@end
```

which avoids both of those issues, but alarm bells are still going off. I may just have to approach what I'm trying to do differently, but if so, what's wrong with this pattern?

Comment: The compiler can't tell that this is a "safe case". Ensuring that external resources are freed is a good use of a finalizer -- however, they should often be accompanied by a way to manually "Dispose" prior to finalizing and this method should be used predominately. This is important because the GC used is *not deterministic* on when the finalizer is called (or the GC is disabled) -- this differs from the traditional ref-counting and dealloc.

Comment: Understand the last bit, but not sure what you mean about the compiler telling whether it's a safe case.

Comment: That is, short of manual inspection and reasoning, there is no general way to know the code in question is "safe". I concur with your stated conclusions. This is the best general guide I know of: [Implementing a finalize Method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/GarbageCollection/Articles/gcFinalize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002453-SW1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule is actually "don't do heavy lifting in either `dealloc` (manual retain-release) or `finalize`".

The problem in both cases is exactly that the object graph local to the object being finalized or deallocated is necessarily in an undefined state *or* you have to enforce a specific order on object destruction, which is a horrible thing to do.

The "no heavy lifting" is a simple rule for expressing that particular detail;  `free()`ing malloc memory is pretty safe because it won't touch the object graph.  But touching other objects is bad and will lead to fragility and/or crashes.

(When porting Xcode from non-GC to GC, one of the single most nasty source of problems was order dependencies -- both known and unknown -- that were in the `dealloc` methods.  By moving to a more formal "invalidation" pattern, where dependencies could be explicitly expressed and enforced, that fragility was eliminated.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, because the objective-C garbage collector is garbage itself :-/ but this is not the place for a rant...

### Simplification 1:

basically, the garbage collector marks all objects that are reachable, and then calls -finalize on all the unreachable objects, in no particular order. Thus, if the object x that is currently having its -finalize method executed has a reference to another object y, then y may have already been finalized when x tries to access y. So you access objects that have already been finalized.

### Simplification 2:

Accessing finalized objects may not seem as bad as it is. Accessing dead (collected) objects is worse. Why can this happen? Objective C uses a generational garbage collector. That means that it is possible that at some point in time, the collector just collects *some* of the unreachable objects. But then, eventually, comes a time when object x has its -finalize method invoked, while x has a strong reference to y, which has already been collected at an earlier GC round. So if x accesses y in any useful way the object is already gone. If the GC is nice, you get a "resurrection" error (yeah, you don't have to make an unreachable object reachable to get resurrection errors.) If it is not nice, something arbitrary will happen.

### Complification:

To make matters more complicate, Cocoa uses many so called 'weak' references. Thus, if I create a window and don't keep a pointer to it alive, it will suddenly vanish :-o After a few of these experiences I banished GC from my project. Now, I can just create a window, and I don't have to keep a pointer of it around, and it still stays alive until it is closed. I think, every `@property (assign)` translates to a `__weak` reference. (Not literally, but this seems to be how much of the AppKit is implemented. Technically, in GC-managed code, `@property (retain)` and `property (assign)` are equivalent.) While seeming sensible at first, I think it makes programming under GC much harder, because the semantics of the program become rather indeterministic.

### Regarding C-Types:

C-Types are not collected by the garbage collector, so you can safely free C-types in your -finalize method. If you don't free them, you will have memory leaks.

Comment: As well, nothing arbitrary happens during collection or finalization.  If you are writing code -- manual retain/release or GC'd -- that has ordering dependencies in your dealloc or finalization, then you should seriously consider revisiting your architecture as that leads to tremendously fragile code (since, by definition, the local object graph of an object being deallocated or finalized is *always* in an undefined state).

Comment: Your opening statement undermines your answer.

Comment: I have an example for arbitrary things to happen. Try using the cocoaasyncsocket library with garbage collection. out of the box, it's just a big memory leak (because gc won't collect CF objects.) if you just create a `-finalize` method and call `-close` all hell breaks loose. All the private instance variables of class AsyncSocket are definitely NOT in an undefined state, when `-dealloc` gets called, but they are in an undefined state when `-finalize` gets called.

Comment: A library that was never properly ported to GC?  That is merely an example of a library that wasn't ported, not proof that order dependencies in `dealloc` are a good idea whereas they aren't possible in `finalize`.   Counter example;  in porting Xcode from non-GC to GC, one of the single largest sources of pain was undoing all the otherwise unknown order dependencies in dealloc that had been accreted over the years.  Not coincidentally, these implied dependencies were a huge source of bugs prior.  One retain/autorelease in the wrong spot and **BOOM**.

Comment: I fully agree that the behavior of `finalize` is *less* deterministic than `dealloc`.  My point is that the claim that `dealloc` is deterministic to the point of being something can rely is both false and a mistake that many have made.